# Simplify setting the same properties multiple times

Tags: floats, optional-arguments

I just found myself having figures that include multiple image files with the exact same options. Is there a way to avoid this repetition? (That would also make it less cumbersome to change these options should the need arise.)

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[trim=1cm 2cm 3cm 4cm,clip]{imagefile1.pdf}
\includegraphics[trim=1cm 2cm 3cm 4cm,clip]{imagefile2.pdf}
\includegraphics[trim=1cm 2cm 3cm 4cm,clip]{imagefile3.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

EDIT: For example in tikz images you could use `\tikzstyle{my style}=[<tikz options>]` (see e.g [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)), is there something similar in plain latex?

Comment: `\foreach \x in {1,...,3} {\includegraphics[trim=1cm 2cm 3cm 4cm,clip]{imagefile\x.pdf}`, with `\usepackage{pgffor}` in the preamble, for example

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `trim` key; however, `clip` seems to be reset at each call, so you need `*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\setkeys{Gin}{trim=1cm 2cm 3cm 4cm}

\includegraphics*{example-image-a} \\
\includegraphics*{example-image-b} \\
\includegraphics*{example-image-c}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't eliminate the separate invocations, but simplifies each invocation, and makes it easy to change the optional parameters for each invocation all at once.

While the MWE does not eliminate separate invocations, that might be done, if the filenames follow a methodical naming convention.  In that case, a `\foreach` look could be set up, as Christian suggested in a comment.

EDITED to provide macro `\settrim` (usage example, `\settrim{1cm 2cm 3cm 4cm}`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\let\trimparms\relax
\newcommand\xincludegraphics[1]{%
  \expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\trimparms]{#1}}
\newcommand\settrim[1]{\def\trimparms{trim=#1,clip}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\settrim{1cm 2cm 3cm 4cm}
\centering
\xincludegraphics{example-image-a}\\
\xincludegraphics{example-image-b}\\
\xincludegraphics{example-image-c}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\settrim{2cm 2cm 4cm 5cm}
\centering
\xincludegraphics{example-image-a}\\
\xincludegraphics{example-image-b}\\
\xincludegraphics{example-image-c}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Let's say I have another such figure with again three pictures with with different settings. Is it better to overwrite `\xincludegraphics` or should I just define a new e.g. `\yincludegraphics`?

Comment: @flawr Please see revision.